# split proxies into IP:PORT:USER:PASS (Python)

Tags: python, proxies

so my proxie file looks like this:

`209.127.191.180:9279:oexuirhs-dest:8rmd80fjmtmj`
`45.95.96.132:8691:oexuirhs-dest:8rmd80fjmtmj`
`193.8.56.119:9183:oexuirhs-dest:8rmd80fjmtmj`
`45.95.99.226:7786:oexuirhs-dest:8rmd80fjmtmj`
`45.95.99.20:7580:oexuirhs-dest:8rmd80fjmtmj`

I would like to split it in IP:PORT:USER:PASS
I thought of using REGEX but I couldn't figure it out I would like it to be a variable that I can later use for example:

IP =
PORT =
USER =
PASS =

this is of course assuming that the proxies and usernames/passwords are different each time
thx already for reading thiss.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(?<ip>((?<ipblock>[0-9]{1,3})\.){3}(?&ipblock)):(?<port>[0-9]+):(?<username>[a-z\-]+):(?<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

This regex contains a capture group for each information.

IP: `(?<ip>((?<ipblock>[0-9]{1,3})\.){3}(?&ipblock))`

The IP Matchgroup explained:

```
(?<ip>                <-- the named group
  (
    (?<ipblock>{1,3}) <-- matches numbers 0 - 999
    \.                <-- ip dot
  ){3}                <-- repeats the whole group three times
  (?&ipblock)         <-- reuses the ipblock match group because of the dot
)
```

---

Port: `(?<port>[0-9]+)`

Username: `(?<username>[a-z\-]+)`

Password: `(?<password>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

> username and password are really basic you probably need to extend it.

you can test your regex here: https://regex101.com/

> This example: https://regex101.com/r/heWm1i/1